# Error while upload data from vf page to excel sheet

Tags: visualforce, xml

I faced following error while uploading data from vf page to excel sheet.Could you please help me how to resolve this issue.

```
{table},
                          base64 = function(s) {
                              return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
                          },
                          format = function(s, c) {
                              return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                                  return c[p];
                              })
                          }
                      return function(table, name, filename) {
                          if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                          var ctx = {
                              worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
                              table: table.innerHTML
                          }
                          document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                          document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
                          document.getElementById("dlink").click();
                      }
                  })();
                  tableToExcel('safetyContracExporttId', sheetName, tableName);
                  document.getElementById('safetyContracExporttId').remove();
```

Comment: indent your code properly and use CTRL+K for formatting

Comment: Could you post what error you are facing.

Comment: Hi Santanu, This code is display on my page when i click on export to excel button

Comment: Hi Muzammil it wouldn't show any error, instead of exporting data into excel it display above code on vf page.

Comment: Then there is some mistake in your logic, if you are exporting the excel, the code should not get printed on screen. It will be rendered as excel.

Comment: Hi Muzammil, Yes , it is code issue